# Celery Periodic task getting executed multiple times

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I have a celery task that is scheduled to run at a specific time of the day.
The problem is this task is getting executed multiple times, so I am receiving the same email at least 2 to 3 times.

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=7, minute=10))
def send_reminder_email_at_7():
    obj = Service()
    obj.send_email()
    return
```

On server, I have setup the project using gunicorn and the supervisor
Following is the configuration of celery and celery beat

```
[program:proj_worker]
command=/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/celery -A baseproj worker -l debug
directory=/home/ubuntu/proj/
user=ubuntu
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/logs/celerylogs/proj_worker.log
stderr_logfile=/home/ubuntu/logs/celerylogs/proj_worker_err.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
killasgroup=true
priority=998
```

```
[program:proj_beat]
command=/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/celery -A baseproj beat -l debug --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
directory=/home/ubuntu/proj/
user=ubuntu
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/logs/celerylogs/proj_beat.log
stderr_logfile=/home/ubuntu/logs/celerylogs/proj_beat_err.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
killasgroup=true
priority=998
```

Following is gunicorn configuration

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/proj
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile /home/ubuntu/logs/gunicorn/gunicorn-access.log --error-logfile /home/ubuntu/logs/gunicorn/gunicorn-error.log  --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/proj/proj.sock baseproj.wsgi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Do you have more than one server with beat?

Comment: No, only one server

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?